# Peewee create an index with type casting

Tags: sql, postgresql, peewee

I've looked around online and haven't been able to find a solution, but apologies if this question has been asked before.

I am trying to create an index on a jsonb column similar to the raw query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table((jb_column::text));
```

where jb_column is the jsonb field.

I'm running into issues applying the index using the model class. I've tried `mytable.add_index(SQL(CREATE INDEX idx ...))`. While this does create the desired index, when I try to reset my database using the built-in `model.delete().execute()` functionality it fails to delete this index.

Therefore, I've also tried creating the index using more built-in peewee functionality. I have attempted:

```
idx = (mytable.index(
           mytable.jb_column.cast('text')))
mytable.add_index(idx)
```

However, this does not create the desired index.  Any advice?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is the SQL evaluated by default (note the collision of the index names):

```
class MyTbl(Model):
    data = BinaryJSONField()

MyTbl.add_index(MyTbl.index(MyTbl.data.cast('text')))
db.create_tables([MyTbl])
```

Produces:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "mytbl" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    "data" JSONB NOT NULL)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "mytbl_data" ON "mytbl" USING GIN ("data")
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "mytbl_data" ON "mytbl" CAST("data" AS text))
```

Solution - specify a name on our custom index:

```
idx = MyTbl.index(MyTbl.data.cast('text'), name='mytbl_data_text')
MyTbl.add_index(idx)
```

Solution 2 - do not use the default GIN index:

```
class MyTbl(Model):
    data = BinaryJSONField(index=False)  # GIN index won't be created.

... add custom index here ...
```